# How to position elements in Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I need to position the elements on the left and right so that the distance on both sides is the same. It needs to be done without margins, does anyone know how? Thanks, my code is below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="#00679F">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/prvired"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_120sdp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/logo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_50sdp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:src="@drawable/logo" />


    </LinearLayout>


    <!--android:layout_below="@+id/start"-->


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/drugiRed"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_17sdp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <!--android:layout_below="@+id/start"-->


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_53sdp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_120sdp"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_20sdp"
            android:background="#00679F"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@+id/sva_vozila"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"

                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_8sdp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_minus26sdp"
                android:text="Unos"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_17ssp" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/sva_vozila"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_25sdp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_20sdp"
                android:background="#00679F"
                android:src="@drawable/input60" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="11dp"
                android:layout_height="5dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
                android:textColor="#F8C304" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_76sdp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_25sdp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_120sdp"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_1sdp"
            android:background="#00679F"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="22dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="-23dp"
                android:text="Voznja"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_17ssp" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/listaImg"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_26sdp"
                android:background="#00679F"
                android:contentDescription="TODO"
                android:onClick="getSvaVozila"
                android:src="@drawable/sedan260" />


        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/treciRed"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_17sdp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_100sdp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_35sdp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_200sdp"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:background="#00679F"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_14sdp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_13sdp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_minus23sdp"
                android:text="Pregled"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_17ssp" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/sveVoznjeImg"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_15sdp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_25sdp"
                android:background="#00679F"
                android:src="@drawable/chart60" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="@dimen/_11sdp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_5sdp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_70sdp"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_60sdp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="#F8C304" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/idEnd"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_130sdp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_200sdp"
            android:background="#00679F"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/vozila"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_30sdp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_27sdp"
                android:background="#00679F"
                android:onClick="getSvaVozila"
                android:src="@drawable/shutdown60" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textview5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_23sdp"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_56sdp"
                android:text="Odjava"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_17ssp" />


        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView

        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:menu="@menu/main_manu"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
        app:itemBackground="@color/blue"
        app:itemIconTint="@android:color/white"
        app:itemTextColor="@android:color/white" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: you want the items to be centered in the middle of the screen so that the distance to the right is the same as the distance to the left ?

Comment: @Zain Yes, you are rigtht!

Comment: Even a `LinearLayout` can do, when setting `layout_gravity`.

Comment: @MartinZeitler Can you please explain better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using linearlayout , this code do exactly what are you asking for , copy it in your layout and see , you have to set the texts and image to yours .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="#00679F">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
            android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginEnd="50dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Header !"
                    android:textSize="24sp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Header !"
                    android:textSize="24sp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginEnd="50dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Header !"
                    android:textSize="24sp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Header !"
                    android:textSize="24sp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    
    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
        app:itemIconTint="@android:color/white"
        app:itemTextColor="@android:color/white" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Enjoy !**

Comment: Thanks, but how to set bottom navigation view, like on this image?

Comment: and I needs dimens just like on this picture, in your code there are too big. Can yu help?

Comment: I updated it , for dimens , i think that you can play with margin end/top/bottom in my code and replace them with yours as you prefer !

Comment: Thanks Mustafa, I will accept your answer. Can you give me your email?

Comment: write it here ?

Comment: OKay, delete it, I will contact you if i need more help :)

Comment: Any time buddy !

Answer (score 0):

So Basically here all the margins are removed, deep nested `RelativeLayout` is expensive, so replaced with `LinearLayouts`, and to center `LinearLayouts` horizontally, you can use `android:gravity="center_horizontal"`, and add a margin in between layouts; I just added 20dp for that.

No need to wrap the logo into a separate layout, so removed that.

You can adjust the vertical margins as you want in below layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#00679F">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_50sdp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_50sdp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:src="@drawable/logo" />

    <!--android:layout_below="@+id/start"-->

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/drugiRed"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/logo"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        
        <!--android:layout_below="@+id/start"-->

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_20sdp"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_20sdp"
            android:background="#00679F"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Unos"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_17ssp" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/sva_vozila"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#00679F"
                android:src="@drawable/input60" />


        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_76sdp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#00679F"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Voznja"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_17ssp" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/listaImg"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#00679F"
                android:contentDescription="TODO"
                android:onClick="getSvaVozila"
                android:src="@drawable/sedan260" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/treciRed"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/drugiRed"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        
        <!--android:layout_below="@+id/start"-->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_20sdp"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_20sdp"
            android:background="#00679F"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Pregled"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_17ssp" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/sveVoznjeImg"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#00679F"
                android:src="@drawable/chart60" />


        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_76sdp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#00679F"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textview5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Voznja"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_17ssp" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/vozila"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#00679F"
                android:contentDescription="TODO"
                android:onClick="getSvaVozila"
                android:src="@drawable/shutdown60" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView

        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:itemBackground="@color/blue"
        app:itemIconTint="@android:color/white"
        app:itemTextColor="@android:color/white"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
        app:menu="@menu/main_manu" />

</RelativeLayout>
```